# Force user change password after first login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Net Core application, I want, after I create an account with a default password,  the next time that user logs in I would like to force them to change their password If `InforceChangePassword` field in database be true.

Note: I want, If the user does not change his password, he will never be able to sign in.

In my code is:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userResolver.GetUserAsync(model.Username);
        if (!user.IsActive)
        {
            return View("Error");
        } 

        if (user != default(TUser)) { 
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id.ToString(), user.UserName));
                if (user.InforceChangePassword)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Manage");
                }

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }

                // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
            }


    }

    // something went wrong, show form with error

    return View("Error");
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: In the above method, the user enters the password change method
But if the user enters the following address into another browser, it is known as the login user.
http: // localhost: 5500

Comment: You should add a claim to the user when he changed the password and check that on every request. If the user has that specific claim, deny him access everywhere except for the change password page

Comment: You should do positive asserts and not negative asserts.  Checking for the existence or value of a claim is better than checking for the non-existence as no claims exist by default.

Comment: Example would be to have a claim for the last password change data then add a handler to Check that claim and redirect to password change page of password change doesn’t exist or is too old.